# The column name or the number of values provided does not match the table definition. creating trigger

Tags: sql, database, triggers

I created a new table in which all the changes in table 2 should be written, and also, for this, I create a trigger that would record data about changes to the table

```
create trigger [BUMBUM_trig] on [employee] 
after update
as
begin
insert [empoyeeaudit]
select NEWID(),'old', position, SUSER_NAME(), HOST_NAME(),getdate() from deleted
insert [empoyeeaudit]
select newid(), 'new', position, SUSER_NAME(), HOST_NAME(),getdate() from inserted
end
```

Comment: Please update your question with the DDL for the empoyeeaudit table

Comment: Apparently, you have columns in the table that you're not updating with your SELECT statement, and the database engine can't tell which ones you want to populate. Either provide a list of columns after the INSERT <table> and before the SELECT, or add the missing columns to your SELECT column list so they get updated as well.

Comment: Also, see [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: And add a tag for the dbms used, to get accurate attention. (The above code is product specific.)